# TImthumb not working for absolute path

Tags: wordpress

Tim thumb script is working fine, My issue is with absolute path and relative path.

when i give relative path, i get the output. but when i use the absolute path, i am getting 403 forbidden error.

I would like to use absolute path. Pleas advise

http://crizaze.com/wp-content/themes/joorang/timthumb.php?src=/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/ami166a-e1295733091216.jpg&h=80&w=80&zc=1

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue before.

The problem was the host/server security setting.

You need to add the following 2 lines to your .htaccess.

```
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPost Off
```

Comment: Wow that blew up my website :/